# Scrapy crawl data inside pdf file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, scrapy, pdf-extraction

I would like to know how to crawl data inside a pdf file using scrapy. Which module should I use and which is the best and effective way?? Could you please give me some sample tutorials on this

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you get the PDF with Scrapy and use [PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) to get the content inside the PDF.

For a complete but somewhat old (using pyPDF) example take a look at [this site](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/03/08/installing-and-using-scrapy-web-crawler-to-search-text-on-multiple-sites/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. I have tried to use the sample site you have given me but I am still getting some errors like *** PdfReadError: EOF marker not found